# C++ linking boost library

Tags: c++, boost, linker

1. First I built the Boost libraries that require building by going to `/usr/local/boost_1_49_0/` and running the `bootstrap.sh`. This went off alright.
2. Step (1) created all the `.so` and `.a` files in `/usr/local/boost_1_49_0/stage/lib`
3. I tested linking against a library, say `lboost_regex` and `#include <boost/regex>` in my source code. This also went off alright.
4. Finally trying out the example on asio, I tried:

   ```
   g++ -I/usr/local/boost_1_49_0 MAIN.cpp -o MAIN -L/usr/local/boost_1_49_0/stage/lib -lboost_thread -lboost_system -lpthread
   ```

(4) compiled alright. But when I run the program with `./MAIN`, I get the following error:

```
./MAIN: error while loading shared libraries: libboost_system.so.1.49.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `-L` option only sets a *compile-time* library search path; if you want a shared library to be found at runtime then its directory must be known at runtime.

One way to set this with `g++` is to pass `-rpath` to the linker, via the compiler; in your case you could say `-Wl,-rpath -Wl,/usr/local/boost_1_49_0/stage/lib`.  (This embeds the directory in the executable.)

Another way is to install the libraries in a place that the linker searches by default (e.g. `/usr/local/lib` might be such a place, depending on how the system is configured).

Yet another way is to set an environment variable such as `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` (Linux or Solaris) or `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` (Mac OS X), to tell the linker where to search when launching executables from the shell where the variable is set.

Comment: Just a warning about rpath - don't do it if you plan to ship the binaries to anyone else (or to other machines). It can be tricky and painful to track down rpath errors.

Comment: That issue can be avoided however by embedding $ORIGIN in the runtime path of the binary.  While a $ORIGIN path is still breakable, it at least makes the search path relative to "wherever the binary is" as opposed to a specific location on the system.

Comment: @KevinGrant alright, thanks that sorted the issue out. though nothing like hassle free -static flag

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure the shared library is in a place where the loader can find it? Either put it in a system wide directory or the same directory as the executable.

[Here's a link with more information about the loader.](http://grahamwideman.wordpress.com/2009/02/09/the-linux-loader-and-how-it-finds-libraries/)